# Why setItemChecked() is not highlighting anything on ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I can't stress out how much I searched here on possible solutions to my issue.
I already tried setting the views and its children to non focusable and the listView choiceMode to multiple.
I also tried using a custom LinearLayout which implements Checkable, but to no avail.

Here is my code (main activity):

```
package com.virosys.amd.activities;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.virosys.amd.Amd;
import com.virosys.amd.DatabaseHandler;
import com.virosys.amd.JsonFunctions;
import com.virosys.amd.PessoaHelper;
import com.virosys.amd.PosterHelper;
import com.virosys.amd.R;
import com.virosys.amd.ServiceHandler;
import com.virosys.amd.adapters.ListaGeneroListAdapter;
import com.virosys.amd.adapters.ListaPessoaListAdapter;
import com.virosys.amd.adapters.ListasListAdapter;
import com.virosys.amd.flowLayout.FlowLayout;
import com.virosys.amd.types.Filme;
import com.virosys.amd.types.FilmePessoa;
import com.virosys.amd.types.Genero;
import com.virosys.amd.types.Lista;
import com.virosys.amd.types.Pessoa;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class FilmeDetalhesActivity extends Activity {

    private int id = 0;
    private Filme f = null;
    private ArrayList<Pessoa> p;
    private DatabaseHandler dh;
    private Button btCadFilme;
    private ServiceHandler sh;


    //Here lies a lot of methods unneeded for this question.
    //unneededMethods(){}


    public void addToLista(View v) { // **********Here is where the fun begins


        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(FilmeDetalhesActivity.this);
        View listSelector = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listas_select, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FilmeDetalhesActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Gerenciar Listas");
        final ListView lvListas = (ListView) listSelector.findViewById(R.id.lvListas);
        builder.setView(listSelector);
        ArrayList<Lista> listas = new ArrayList<>();
        if (dh == null) {
            dh = new DatabaseHandler(FilmeDetalhesActivity.this);
        }
        ListasListAdapter lla = new ListasListAdapter(FilmeDetalhesActivity.this, dh.getListas());
        try {
            lla.isEmpty();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            lla = null;
        }
        if (lla != null) {
            lvListas.setAdapter(lla);
        }
        lvListas.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); // Tried this, didn't work.
        lvListas.setItemsCanFocus(false);// Tried this, didn't work.
        lvListas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                lvListas.setItemChecked(position, !lvListas.isItemChecked(position)); // This ultimately drove me mad.
                Toast.makeText(FilmeDetalhesActivity.this, String.valueOf(lvListas.isItemChecked(position)),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Seems this status is always false.
            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("Atualizar Listas!", null);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null);
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
//      alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//                  @Override
//                  public void onClick(View v) {
//                      alert.cancel();
//                  }
//              });
//      alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              String lista = lvListas.getText().toString();
//              if (!lista.trim().isEmpty()) {
//                  dh.createLista(lista);
//                  AlertDialog.Builder ok = new AlertDialog.Builder(FilmeDetalhesActivity.this);
//                  ok.setMessage("Lista " + lista + " criada com sucesso!");
//                  ok.setPositiveButton("Continuar", null);
//                  ok.show();
////                    listar();
//                  alert.dismiss();
//              } else {
//                  Toast.makeText(FilmeDetalhesActivity.this, "Digite um nome para a lista!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
//                          .show();
//              }
//          }
//      });
//
//      dh.addToLista(f, listas);
    }
}
```

The list adapter:

```
package com.virosys.amd.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.virosys.amd.R;
import com.virosys.amd.types.Filme;
import com.virosys.amd.types.Lista;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListasListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Lista> {

    private Typeface font;

    public ListasListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Lista> listas, Typeface font) {
        super(context, 0, listas);
        this.font = font;
    }

    public ListasListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Lista> listas) {
        super(context, 0, listas);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Lista lista = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listaritemmodel, parent, false);
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selected);
            convertView.setFocusable(false);
            convertView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        }

        TextView tvNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listaLabelTitulo);
        TextView tvId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listaLabelId);
        tvNome.setText(lista.getNome());
        tvNome.setTypeface(font);
        tvNome.setSelected(true);
        tvId.setText(String.valueOf(lista.getId()));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The custom LinearLayout (implementing checkable):

```
package com.virosys.amd;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/*
 * This class is useful for using inside of ListView that needs to have checkable items.
 */
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
    private CheckedTextView _checkbox;

    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        // find checked text view
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
            View v = getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof CheckedTextView) {
                _checkbox = (CheckedTextView)v;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return _checkbox != null && _checkbox.isChecked();
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (_checkbox != null) {
            _checkbox.setChecked(checked);
        }
        if (checked) {
            this.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.DarkPurple));
        } else {
            setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        if (_checkbox != null) {
            _checkbox.toggle();
        }
    }
}
```

The layout file for the backgroundResource (also didn't work):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/Transparent" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@color/DarkPurple" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@color/DarkPurple" />
</selector>
```

What could I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a LinearLayout that implements Checkable or the selector xml. What you should do is, pass the listview into the adapter, and in getView of your adapter, add some code like this:

```
if(listView.isItemChecked(position)) {
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.DarkPurple);
} else {
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Transparent);
}
```

And in your activity, just do this:

```
lvListas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        lla.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify: I managed to get the results I wanted by keeping the CheckableLinearLayout. Without it, the list item would still toggle selection between true and false, but I couldn't make it keep the desired color when selected.

Comment: Did you add the first piece of code I pasted? Because I tried and it works with no problem.

Comment: How can I reference the ListView inside the adapter?

Comment: Just add the ListView as a parameter in the adapter's constructor, or add a setListView() method in the adapter.